# Job Hunting for a postdoc

Tags: job-search, postdocs, job

I just finished my postdoc in Bimolecular engineering and I am hunting for a job, or a position.But my concern is that out of almost 80 jobs that I applied over the last two months, I have not received any feedback yet. I am not sure what the problem is, but there is even no notice of rejection! Could it be normal?

Comment: Many institutions wait to send rejection letters until long after the position is filled, even for candidates who were eliminated from consideration almost immediately.  Sometimes they never send rejection letters at all.

Comment: Out of more than a hundred faculty application I made over a number of years, I received exactly four notifications that I didn't get the job from actual human beings and about 25 automated notifications. I found out that I didn't get the job more often from rumor mills or simply seeing a new name on the department's faculty page than from any formal effort on the part of the employer.

Answer (score 1):

It is becoming harder even for top schools graduates but you should check the status of your application, either by checking it online or directly contacting the professors who you plan to work with. Most rejections will come late in April or May. Try to check with the positions that are directly related to your research and continue to apply for new openings.